# Window.postMessage not working in lightning community site

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, aura, work.com, postmessage

We have work.com managed package installed in our org. Some buttons in the managed package component are not working in the community site. When I inspected the code source, those buttons are frozen in window.postMessage execution.

[image]

Same component if I try to use in different community site of same org, then the buttons are working. This seems to be weird, Not sure if there is any specific security restriction that is blocking the window.postmessage to execute. Need advice here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: whats the targetOrigin you are passing?

Comment: This is managed package. So I can't edit the code. I found they are using  "window.location.origin" as targetOrigin